# Idf_tools.py syntax errors in Clion

Tags: python, clion, esp-idf

Unfortunatelly, i got syntax errors in JetBrains CLion, when i load any ESP-IDF example/helloword  projects. But, just in Clion. If i build the same project in terminal/console, there is no error at all.
For example, here is a simple fprint with syntax error. Maybe there is a python version config mistake in my CLion setting?... i don't know...

```
-- Checking Python dependencies...
  File "/Users/viktor/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py", line 369
    info(f'Downloading {url}')
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use python 3.9.12 on macOSX and as i mentioned, I can build any ESP-IDF project without CLion.
Somebody can help me, how to config CLion?
Thanxxx!

Comment: I don't believe you're actually running this under Python 3.9 as you claim, as this is exactly the error that results from trying to use a f-string on older Python versions.

Comment: I think, you are right, maybe the reason is an older Python version in Clion. But how can I config it?

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault. I used own bash environment, where python version was 3.9.12, but the Clion used system environment, where the python version was 2.7. So, I had to change the system python version on mac.